# Python find average of element in list with multiple elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a ticker that grabs current information of multiple elements and adds it to a list in the format: trade_list.append([[trade_id, results]]).

Say we're tracking trade_id's 4555, 5555, 23232, the trade_list will keep ticking away adding their results to the list, I then want to find the averages of their results individually.

The code works as such:

```
Find accounts
for a in accounts:
   find open trades of accounts
   for t in range(len(trades)):
      do some math
   trades_list.append(trade_id,result)
   avernum = 0
   average = []
   for r in range(len(trades_list)):
      average.append(trades_list[r][1]) # This is the value attached to the trade_id
       avernum+=1
   results = float(sum(average)/avernum))
   results_list.append([[trade_id,results]])
```

This fills out really quickly. This is after two ticks:

print(results_list)
[[[53471, 28.36432]], [[53477, 31.67835]], [[53474, 32.27664]], [[52232, 1908.30604]], [[52241, 350.4758]], [[53471, 28.36432]], [[53477, 31.67835]], [[53474, 32.27664]], [[52232, 1908.30604]], [[52241, 350.4758]]]

These averages will move and change very quickly. I want to use results_list to track and watch them, then compare previous averages to current ones

Thinking:

```
for r in range(len(results_list)):
   if results_list[r][0] == trade_id:
       restick.append(results_list[r][1])
resnum = len(restick)
if restick[resnum] > restick[resnum-1]:
   do fancy things
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve. And do add the code into your question, so it will be easy to get it.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: So `trade_list` is a list containing lists containing lists of the form `[trade_id, results]`? That is, you have three levels of lists, not two?

Comment: From your explanation it's unclear what you are trying to do and what your specific problem is. It'd help if you could provide a minimal working example.

Comment: It would only make sense to have a list of "tuples" of `[trade_id, result]` but this is unclear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some short code that does what you I think you have described, although I might have misunderstood. You basically do exactly what you say; select everything that has a certain trade_id and returns its average.:

```
TID_INDEX = 0
DATA_INDEX = 1

def id_average(t_id, arr):
    filt_arr = [i[DATA_INDEX] for i in arr if i[TID_INDEX] == t_id]
    return sum(filt_arr)/len(filt_arr)
```